# How to load two texts from db like in the picture?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

How to load two texts like in the picture? That is, I have two texts stored in the database, one in English, the other in Russian. I am using a php script to load from the database. I also use Retrofit. How to take a string from two texts in turn and load it into a textview

[this is what i want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rupl6.jpg)

UPDATE: I have two lyrics, one in English, the other in Russian. I need to pull out one line from the English text, and immediately below it the line from the Russian

[db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GiYTG.png)

Comment: How are the strings store in your database?

Comment: Lucadmin, i changed the post. Please take a look

Comment: You could always add a new TextView to a List View, whenever there is a linebreak

Comment: Do not quite understand

Comment: You can check if the text has a break. Like when it switches line. And then u split the text in all the different sentences. Afterwards you can assert the translation to the original text

Comment: Lucadmin, Is it worth checking in the adapter?

Comment: I would split the text in the lines before and then give the the adapter two Strings for each line to create a List View. And each line has its own ListView.